# TextMate transform to replace single character in matched repetitive group

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, textmate

TL;DR
show me a general vscode snippet to transform "/home/me/projects/project/src/Commands/Interfaces/Whatever" to "Commands\Interfaces\Whatever"

Hi all,
I'm using Vscode and trying to figure out a simple transform of the file directory to insert the PHP namespace.
So far i could not figure out a simple, general solution to this seemingly mundane problem:

- Is there a way to transform PART of the TM_DIRECTORY variable in a snippet, so that every forward slash becomes a backward slash?

This seems so trivial at first, right? start from

```
${TM_DIRECTORY/\\//\\\\/}
```

Then buid up from there. Problem is, I want to catch only part of the filename, THEN transform slashes on the catched group, without resorting to a fixed/maximum number of filename components (in that case, there is an ugly, lengthy solution)

Is the following in the right direction? If so, what replacement string results in
group $1 but with slashes reverted?

```
${TM_DIRECTORY/.*\\/src(\\/([^\\/]+))+$/??????/}
```

Thanks in advance, an acceptable response is "there is just no way unless you relax your requirements", this is more of a theoretical question on the power of regexes.

**Edit:**

Kudos to @WiktorStribiżew who found the simplest solution, after I posted the question I came up with a far more complicated expression than his:

```
${TM_DIRECTORY/(([^\\/]+)\\/?(?=.*\\/src\\/))|(\\/src\\/)|((?<=\\/src\\/.*)\\/?([^\\/]+))/${5:+\\\\}$5/g}
```

Comment: This is really possible with VSCode regex replace syntax which is enhanced with additional replacement operators. See the [allowed grammar here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
"${TM_DIRECTORY/^.*?[\\\\\\/]src[\\\\\\/]|([\\\\\\/])/${1:+\\\\}/g}"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCcPcn/5) (there is an extra `\` at the start of the resulting string as there is no way to introduce the conditional replacement pattern as in VS Code).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `[\\\/]` - `/` or `\` char
- `src` - the directory name up to which you need to remove the subdirs
- `[\\\/]` - a `/` or `\` char
- `|` - or
- `([\\\/])` - Group 1: a `/` or `\` char.

The `${1:+\\}` replacement means we replace with `\` only when Group 1 match occurs.

Note the backslashes need doubling, and `g` at the end replaces all occurrences.

Comment: God I feel so dumb. Thank you Wiktor, once I wrapped my mind over the fact that you MUST use partial matching instead of the whole path and conditional substitution, I found a solution by myself, but yours is much more concise (I used assertions to figure out if I am before or after the separator).

Comment: Sorry @Wiktor, I found the solution just minutes after I posted the question and I didn't expect a solution so soon,